# How to find the cumulative sum of a column in pyspark with multiple files

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc

I have a multiple CSV files, where each csv have 1 month of data.

I want to add an extra column like Cumulative sum of a column of last 3 days.

I have the partial solution here:

```
grouped_df = df.groupBy("province_state","date").sum('confirmed','deaths','recovered','active').orderBy("province_state","date")
window = Window.partitionBy("province_state").orderBy("date").rowsBetween(-3, 0)
window_df = grouped_df.select("*",sum('sum(active)').over(window).alias("3_days_window_active"))

year_month_df = window_df.select("*",date_format("date", "yyyy-MM").alias("YYYY-MM"))
year_month_df.write.option("header", True) \
                        .partitionBy("province_state","YYYY-MM")\
                        .mode("overwrite")\
                        .csv("state")
```

But this is only working for one csv. How to modify this code to work for multiple csv files?
I'm not interested in appending these csv files. I need a solution where I will run the job today for this month, and I have to run other job next month.
my issue is how to get the cumulative value for date 2020-04-01 in below example?

Please suggest some ideas..

```
EX: CSV-1
Date        value     cum_value
2020-03-25   7          7
2020-03-26   1          8
2020-03-27   1          9
2020-03-28   2          4
2020-03-29   4          7
2020-03-30   2          8
2020-03-31   6          12


CSV-2:
Date        value     cum_value
2020-04-01   7          15
2020-04-02   11         24
2020-04-03   13         31
2020-04-04   21         45
2020-04-05   40         73
2020-04-06   29         90
2020-04-07   60         129
```

Comment: if the schema of all files are same, you can read all of them in one go and then go the cumsum operations. finally, write the result partitioned by the same fields

Comment: No, I don't have all the files right now. I will get a new csv file every month.

Comment: you can't achieve what you're looking for without reading all files. at least not in a straightforward way.